# How can I decompress gzipped http bodies in a nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, http, zlib

First off, I tried all that I could find anywhere on the web, including the answers to related questions on SO, but could not make anything work. That's why I'm asking a new question.

I use the Lua filter on envoy to send headers and body chunks to a simple node application which just writes them to files. In the node application I receive headers and body chunks together with a http transaction index and whether they belong to the request or the response, and am therefore able to reconstruct the request and the response in their entirety.

On occasion, I get a response sent from the Lua filter that is gzipped. No matter how I try to employ node's zlib library, I always get the same error when trying to decompress it.

For example, these being the response contents (body truncated and irrelevant headers removed):

```
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
transfer-encoding: chunked

�ėmo ...
```

When I remove the headers and the newlines before the body starts that I know I add myself, when writing the file, and try to decompress the remaining part with:

```
let compressed = fs.readFileSync(...);
zlib.gunzip(compressed, function(err, uncompressed) {
    console.log(uncompressed);
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    }
});
```

I always get this error:

> Error: incorrect header check

I get the same error with code like this:

```
var buffer = [];
gunzip.on('data', function(data) {
    buffer.push(data.toString())
}).on("end", function() {
    console.log(buffer.join(""));
}).on("error", function(e) {
    console.log("Error: " + e.message);
})
let compressed = fs.readFileSync(...);
gunzip.write(compressed);
```

If I capture the same request with `tcpdump`, I can see that what I get in the tcp stream and what's in the data sent from the Lua filter to node is similar. However, if I load the tcp dump in wireshark, it will properly decompress the data when I ask it to follow the http stream, so I *know* the data is valid and there is a way to decompress it.

What's the correct way to decompress chunks in a gzip-ed http body using JavaScript running on node?

Comment: Can you share the first few bytes of the file as a hexdump?

Comment: I can, but I won't - makes no sense, after what I found after I posted the question. Looking more carefully into the tcp dump, I found that due to me handling the request improperly in node (encoding related issues, I believe) I do not, in effect, attempt to gunzip what the Lua filter actually sends. I will put some more effort into it today, to properly handle the request body, and delete the question if I get it working. If I don't, I will update the question - will add the gzip header to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, PEBCAK - sort of. But I will leave this here in case someone else runs into a similar problem.

What I started out with was something like this - given that I was only expecting plain text data:

```
let data = "";
request.on("data", chunk => {
    data += chunk.toString();
});
request.on("end", chunk => {
    if (chunk) {
        data += chunk.toString();
    }
    doSomethingWithTheBinaryData(data);
}
```

This, however, was pushing binary data into strings, causing the binary content to be modified, and `zlib` to no longer be able to decompress it. The proper way to receive binary data is:

A proper way to receive binary data from an http request is something like:

```
let data = [];
request.on("data", chunk => {
    data.push(chunk);
});
request.on("end", chunk => {
    if (chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    }
    allData = Buffer.concat(data);
    doSomethingWithTheBinaryData(allData);
}
```

Once I switched to this second form, both text and compressed data started to be received and processed correctly.